# C++ function gets specific functor but uses function from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters, operator-keyword, functor

```
class A {
   virtual void operator()(int a, int b) { cout << a + b << endl; }
};
class B : A {
   void operator()(int a, int b) { cout << a - b << endl; }
};
void f(int a, int b, const A &obj) {
   obj(a, b);
}
int main() {
   int a = 5, b = 3;;
   B obj;
   f(a, b, obj); // should give 2, but gives 8 (uses A's function even if it's virtual)
}
```

It doesnt use operator() from class B but uses one frome class A (even though it's set as virtual so it should use B's op()).
Any idea how to fix it?

**tl;dr** - when i give as parameter (which type is most-basic class) object of specific class that inherit from base class, i want to use specific operator, not the base one.

Comment: Post real code. This doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You must inherit `public` to have polymorphism:

```
// .......vvvvvv (omitting `public` means `private` by default
class B : public A {
//...
```

Also:

- you cannot call non-`const` member functions on `const` object, so make `operator()` to be `const`
- the operators must be `public`, not `private`
- add `return` in the `main` (not mandatory, but as the function is `int main` and it's good to have a `return`)

Comment: Ok i've managed to make this work... though thanks :)
as for const - i forgot them (wrote quick code withouth running it..) same reason for main return ;)

Comment: @RippeR Can you post the actual problem code b/c as stated in the problem it could not have compiled and supplied that answer, otherwise this is not a real question

Comment: Why add return in main? Not mandatory (right), but still (still what?)

Comment: Original code (without Graph class, it's not needed i guess) is something like here (i've already modyfied it to work and don't have it full anymore):
http://pastebin.com/W3XMT0rF (not sure if can paste code in comments, so i put it there). It didn't work as i wanted (always used A' operator() even if object was from B, so i've rewriten it and now somehow magicly works ... Must have been a misspell or something like that i guess.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan - edited (if it matters at all)